# Make unique proxy for many instances in linked file

Tags: linked-data, instances, proxies

Have one file with "window" which frame shape can be changed using bevel object.
Frame has attached hook for scaling without affecting frame shape.
Also have a "glass" mesh. Glass and frame are grouped.

Second file gets linked group from the first one. I use proxy for location and scaling the group in second file.

Question: I'd like to have few instances of frames in second file with various sizes and locations. I can make duplicate of a frame by Ctrl+D, but I can't make individual proxy for duplicate, because every proxy just affects all copies, but not the individual one.

[First](http://xn--80aqfbtfmbefc.xn--p1ai/blender/scaling_frame.blend)
[Second](http://xn--80aqfbtfmbefc.xn--p1ai/blender/linkedtest.blend)

OR

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Please only use [blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) for the blend file hosting here. (I for one will not click on those links).